# npm install java gives error

Tags: java, node.js, npm, node-java

I downloaded the node-java repo from https://github.com/joeferner/node-java. And I am currently using java version 1.7.0_79. My system variable in the control panel points to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;more here

I run npm install java but I am getting the following error

```
> java@0.7.1 install C:\Users\kmidha\Desktop\node_modules\java
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\kmidha\Desktop\node_modules\java>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild 
child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
[node-java] Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "reg query "hklm\software\javasoft\java development kit""
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.



Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "reg query "hklm\software\wow6432node\javasoft\java development kit""
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.


gyp: Call to 'node findJavaHome.js' returned exit status 1. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kmidha\Desktop\node_modules\java
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "java"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! java@0.7.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.7.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the java package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls java
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kmidha\Desktop\npm-debug.log
```

I even tried to run node findJavaHome.js but I get this error

```
[node-java] Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "reg query "hklm\software\javasoft\java development kit""
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "reg query "hklm\software\wow6432node\javasoft\java development kit""
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

I am using windows 7. I tried searching but couldn't find out. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have the Java JDK installed on your machine?

Comment: @tier1 yes I have. Jave JDK 7 and JRE 7 are installed

Comment: @KanikaMidha did you get anything or not ??

Comment: I was getting same error message on Windows 10. Installing JDK 1.8 have resolved the issue. I am running Node.js 4.4.7 and NPM 3.10.6.